# What if I try to assign values greater than pow(2,64)-1 to unsigned long long in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, types, range

If I have two unsigned long long values say pow(10,18) and pow (10,19) and I multiply them and store the output in another variable of type unsigned long long...the value which we get is obviously not the answer but does it have any logic? We get a junk type of value each time we try to this with arbitrarily large numbers, but do the outputs have any logic with the input values?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193880/overflowing-of-unsigned-int

Comment: If they are constants then just type them in stead of computing them each time the program is executed

Answer (score 10):

Unsigned integral types in C++ obey the rules of modular arithmetic, i.e. they represent the integers modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>, where *N* is the number of value bits of the integral type (possibly less than its `sizeof` times `CHAR_BIT`); specifically, the type holds the values [0, 2<sup>*N*</sup>).

So when you multiply two numbers, the result is the remainder of the mathematical result divided by 2<sup>*N*</sup>.

The number *N* is obtainable programmatically via [`std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits).

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer which also mentions CHAR_BIT

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a logic.

As KerreK wrote, integers are "wrapped around" the 2<sup>*N*</sup> bits that constitute the width of their datatype.

To make it easy, let's consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    unsigned char tot;

    unsigned char ca = 200;
    unsigned char ca2 = 200;

    tot = ca * ca2;

    cout << (int)tot;

    return 0;
}
```

(try it: http://ideone.com/nWDYjO)

In the above example an unsigned char is 1 byte wide (max 255 decimal value), when multiplying 200 * 200 we get 40000. If we try to store it into the unsigned char it won't obviously fit.

The value is then "wrapped around", that is, **tot** gets the result of the following

```
(ca*ca2) % 256
```

where 256 are the bit of the unsigned char (1 byte), 2<sup>*8*</sup> bits

In your case you would get

> (pow(10,18) * pow (10,19)) %
>   2<sup>number_of_bits_of_unsigned_long_long(architecture_dependent)</sup>

Comment: btw in C++ its better to use `#include <cmath>` instead of `#include <math.h>`

Comment: I agree, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: To be pedantic, the *N* is not necessarily the width of the type. In general there may be padding. Only the `char` types and the `intNN_t`/`uintNN_t` types are guaranteed not to have padding.