# Unsigned integer in C++

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I write the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

   unsigned int i=1;
   i=i-3;
   cout<<i;
   return 0;
}
```

The output is a garbage value, which is understandable.
Now I write the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {

    unsigned int i=1;
    i=i-3;
    i=i+5;
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output is 3. What's happening here? How is the garbage value being added by 5 here?

Comment: it's not garbage, the value underflows round to unsigned int max value - 2, you then added 5 to this so it becomes positive 3

Comment: Look it up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Unsigned integers overflow in a well-defined manner (unlike signed integers). Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193880/overflowing-of-unsigned-int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of the values of `unsigned int` being drawn on a large clock face with the largest possible value (UINT_MAX) being next to zero.

Subtracting 3 from 1 moves you 3 places back on the clock (which gives you UINT_MAX - 1), and adding 5 to this moves you 5 places forward.

The net effect is to add 2 to 1, but it's important to know that the *intermediate* value is perfectly well defined by the C++ standard. It is **not** garbage, but related to the value of `UINT_MAX` on your platform.

Note that the well-defined nature of this overflow is not true for `signed` types. The behaviour on overflowing a `signed` type is *undefined* in C++.

Comment: Should I consider the difference between 0 and INT_MAX  1?

Comment: Did you mean UINT_MAX? If so then consider the difference between 0 and UINT_MAX to be -1. You're then consistent with unsigned arithmetic. Assigning a value of `-1` to an `unsigned` type is defined to yield UINT_MAX.

Comment: Yeah UINT_MAX. I referred 1 to be the absolute difference between 0 and UINT_MAX.It is clear now.