# Can't understand unsigned int type in C

Tags: c, types, int, unsigned-integer

I'm starting to program in C and I'm having a problem to understand some results I'm getting. I'll paste the code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x = 0;

    printf("%u\n",x-1);
    return 0;
}
```

The terminal is returning 4.294.967.295, and I'm not getting why. I know that this value is the max value of a `unsigned int`, but actually I was expecting some warning from the compiler that I would have to use a `int` type not an `unsigned int` because the result is negative. Anyway, can someone help me?

Comment: Actually, it overflows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988588/is-using-unsigned-integer-overflow-good-practice

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable

Comment: @Mihai - Wouldn't this be underflow?

Comment: I got it now! Thank you everyone! :)

Comment: Technically, unsigned arithmetic *never overflows* (because it is performed modulo 2^N as per the Standard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an unsigned type all of the bits are used to represent non-negative values ( i.e., >= 0).  Think of this as the values wrapping around, so when you decrement below the lower limit (0), you wrap around to the largest value (with 32 bits, 2^32 - 1).

Also, note you did not *assign* a negative value to variable `x`, you just provided an expression that subtracted 1 from it. I.e.,

```
x-1
```

vs

```
x = x - 1;
```

though whether you would have gotten a warning about this would probably depend on the compiler and the warning levels set.

Answer (score 1):

It's the fixed number of bits (32), and [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_complement) that get you here.

Comment: Twos's complement is for signed numbers.  These are unsigned binary representations without a sign bit.

Comment: Yes, but the machine doesn't care.

Comment: @nikolai; unsigned are defined to be arithmetic modulo 2^N. The machine *might* care under certain circumstances. But there's no concept of over/underflow for modulo arithmetic. Modulo 4, 3 + 1 is 0, and there's no overflow. Whereas with integers, adding 1 to a number can cause overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned int` as it's name implies has no sign.

`unsigned int` values are represented as a 32 bit values, so when you subtract one it rolls over from 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF, that gives you the 4294967295 you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard says that all unsigned arithmetic happens within the modulo 2^N range, where N is the number of bits in the type. Thus, substracting 1 from 0 in unsigned arithmetic does not result in -1, but in UINT_MAX.

Think of the unsigned values as a ring, where 0 is glued next to UINT_whatever. Regardless of whether you are adding, subtracting, shifting, multiplying, even negating, you'll never leave the ring. So you are perfectly allowed to do things like

```
 unsigned int x = -1;    /* Assigns UINT_MAX. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned means that you have only positive values. Computers stores numbers as binary with some rules. When you do 0 - 1 you got maximum int value. You may read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: Bzzt: 0 is unsigned, but not positive :-)

Comment: I mean non-negative ;). But there are also +0 and -0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `unsigned int` cannot store negative integers.

Please read up about ones-complement and twos-complex numbers.

What is happening that the top bit is being set along with the others and is then interpreted as a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the error because the compiler can't know what will you do in future.