# UINT_MAX + 1 equals what?

Tags: c, standards, portability

What is the defined behavior in C for `UINT_MAX + 1u`? How safe is to assume it is zero?

Comment: @JoshPetitt: That's still zero by the way. `UINT_MAX + 1u` is evaluated as an unsigned integer, resulting in `0`, which is then stored in a `long long`. ;-)

Comment: @netcoder, on my Windows 64-bit machine you are indeed correct.  My internal compiler is flawed. :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the standard (C11, 6.2.5/9, emphasis mine):

> [...] A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
>    because a result that cannot be represented by **the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
>   represented by the resulting type**.

If `UINT_MAX` is `10`:

```
(10 + 1) % (10 + 1) == 0
```

So, yes, it's safe to assume it's zero.

Comment: The standard mandates that `UINT_MAX` (and the maximal values of other unsigned integer types) is `2^N - 1`, where `N` is the width of the type, so 10 is a bad example (but that doesn't stop me from upvoting).

Comment: Furthermore, `(unsigned) -1 == UINT_MAX`; the latter can be used in preprocessor conditions, while `(unsigned) -1` can only be evaluated by the compiler.

Answer (score 12):

It's worth emphasizing that while *unsigned* behavior is well-defined, *signed* integer overflow isn't:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

> In the C programming language, signed integer overflow causes
>   undefined behavior, while unsigned integer overflow causes the number
>   to be reduced modulo a power of two

A very good paper on the subject:

- http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/overflow12.pdf

EXAMPLES OF C/C++ INTEGER OPERATIONS AND THEIR RESULTS

```
Expression             Result
----------             ------
UINT_MAX+1             0
LONG_MAX+1             undefined
INT_MAX+1              undefined
SHRT_MAX+1             SHRT_MAX+1 if INT_MAX>SHRT_MAX, otherwise undefined
char c = CHAR_MAX; c++ varies
-INT_MIN               undefined
(char)INT_MAX          commonly -1
1<<-1                  undefined
1<<0                   1
1<<31                  commonly INT_MIN in ANSI C and C++98; undefined in C99 and C++11
1<<32                  undefined
1/0                    undefined
INT_MIN%-1             undefined in C11, otherwise undefined in practice
```

Answer (score 5):

It's safe. The C standard guarantees that unsigned integer <s>overflow</s> wrap-around results in zero.

Comment: And C strictly speaking, unsigned integers never overflow only signed integers overflow.

Comment: @ouah In this case, what should I say they do?

Comment: @H2CO3: you could say they wrap around.

Answer (score 2):

Should be safe:

[Wiki on unsigned overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Note the unsigned int overflow is well defined.

Also, here's a [whole question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988588/is-using-unsigned-integer-overflow-good-practice) on this.