# Integer promotion between unsigned and int

Tags: c++, c++11, integer-promotion

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398959/c-crashes-in-a-for-loop-with-a-negative-expression?newsletter=1&nlcode=70673%7cc3fa)

```
std::string s{ "aa" }; 
s.length() - 3;  // == very large number
```

From memory, C's integer promotion rules (idk about C++) produce a type wide enough to fit the result of the calculation and favour unsigned types (for the extra bit of width). But `3` is of type `int` (right?). So why is the result of type `unsigned` instead of `int` or `long`? `unsigned` is certainly **not** wide enough to capture the result of the expression!

Comment: `s.length()` is unsigned so `3` is promoted to unsigned before doing the subtraction.  Wrap of unsigned subtraction is well defined.  There is a discussion paper on why making the Standard Library container size types unsigned is a problem and that they should all be signed, but that it is too late to change now.

Comment: From c++20, there is [std::ssize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`string::length` has type `size_t`. For x86-64 platforms modern compilers define `size_t` as `uint64_t`. Therefore 3 is promoted to `uint64_t`. Compiler can not promote it to `long` or even `long long` (aka `int64_t`) because, for example, `(1<<64) - 2` can not be represented in signed 64-bit integer.
As mentioned in comments, there is `string::ssize` in C++20 for signed size value.